# Representative Set for Relation $S$ on $\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$ s.t. $\langle f,g\rangle\in S\iff\exists$ bijection $h:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ s.t.$f=g\circ h$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

**Problem**: Define a relation $ S $ on $ \Bbb N \to \{0,1\} $ as follows:
$ \langle f,g \rangle \in S \iff  $ there exists a bijection $ h: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N $ s.t. $ f = g \circ  h $.
$ S $ is an equivalence relation on $ \Bbb N \to \{0,1\} $ (no need to prove this). Write a Representative set for the relation $ S $. There's no need to prove that the relation you wrote is indeed a Representative set.

**Reminder**: Suppose $ T \subseteq X \times X $ is an equivalence relation over $ X $. $~~ A \subseteq X $ will be called a Representative set of $ T $, if it occurs that: $ \forall x \in X. | [x]_T \cap A | =1 $.

**Attempt:**
I don't really know what Representative set to define. It seems to me I'm missing something simple here. I tried to look at the functions:
$ f_1(n) = 0 , f_2(n) =1,f_3(n) = \begin{cases} 0  & \text{n=0}\\ 1  &\text{else}\end{cases} $ ,$ f_4(n) = \begin{cases} 0  & n \in \Bbb N_{even}
\\ 1 & n \in \Bbb N_{odd} \end{cases} , \forall n \in \Bbb N$ .
None of these functions relate through relation $ S $ since there does not exist a bijection between them. I feel lost, do you have any idea what to do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about what the equivalence classes look like. For example, why aren't the functions $f_2$ and $f_3$ equivalent?

Comment: Since there isn't a bijection, I can't see any other reason. The equivalence classes are: $ [f_1] = \{ f_1 \}  , [ f_2] = \{ f_2 \} , [f _3 ] = \{f_3\} , [f_4] = \{ f_4\}$

Comment: The equivalence classes aren't necessarily containing just one element (though in two cases it does, $f_1$ and $f_2$). For example, why is the function $f_5(n) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $n=1$,} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$ equivalent to $f_3$? Why is the function $f_6(n) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $n$ is divisible by $3$,} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$ equivalent to $f_4$?

Comment: Something that might help you better understand these functions is to make use of the standard one-to-one correspondence between $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (namely, a function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ is identified with the subset $f^{-1}(1) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$). What does the equivalence relation mean in the context of that correspondence?

Comment: Very interesting... I think I need to look at this differently but I can't grasp how. Naively there's a bijection between those functions you wrote, I can't really think what they are.  Also, I know that $ | \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} | = | \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) | = 2^{\aleph_0}  $ so this means there's a bijection between these two sets.

Comment: Think more about the general cases of those aforementioned equivalences. What needs to be true about $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ for the function $f_A(n) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $n \in A$,} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$ to be equivalent to $f_3$? What needs to be true about $B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ for the function $f_B(n) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $n \in B$,} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$ to be equivalent to $f_4$?

Comment: Well, the characteristic function is a standard one-to-one correspondence between $ \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} $ and $ \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) $. I still dont see the how set $ f^{-1}(1) \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ plays any role here.

Comment: The characteristic function takes a value of $1$ when the argument is in the set and $0$ otherwise. So $f^{-1}(1)$ is that aforementioned set if $f$ is to be its characteristic function. (And in case there's any confusion about notation, I mean $f^{-1}(1) = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid f(n) = 1\}$, sometimes also written $f^{-1}[1]$, $f^{-1}(\{1\})$, $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A representative set would be $\{f : \mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\} | f$ is monotonic$\} \cup \{h\}$, where $h(n)$ is defined s.t. $h(n) \equiv n \mod 2$.

Here, a monotonic function is one which is either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing.

Let's prove that this is a representative set.

Consider some function $g : \mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$. Consider $S_i = g^{-1}(i)$ for $i = 0, 1$. Each $S_i$ is either finite or infinite.

If $S_0$ and $S_1$ are both finite, then $\mathbb{N} = S_0 \cup S_1$ is finite. This is contradictory.

If $S_0$ and $S_1$ are both infinite, then they must both be in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. So we take some bijections $k : \mathbb{N} \to S_0$ and $j : \mathbb{N} \to S_0$. Then consider the bijection $u(n) = k(n / 2)$ if $n$ is even, $u(n) = j((n - 1) / 2)$ if $n$ is odd. Then $u$ is a bijection, and $g \circ u = h$.

Suppose only one is finite: WLOG, take $S_0$ finite and $S_1$ infinite. Then take $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and bijections $k : \{n \in \mathbb{N} | n < m\} \to S_0$ and $j : \mathbb{N} \to S_1$. Define the bijection $u(n) = k(n)$ if $n < m$, $u(n) = k(n - m)$ if $n \geq m$. Then $g \circ u$ is a monotonically increasing function $\mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$.

I'll leave it as an exercise to show that this is the only member of the representative set equivalent to $g$. Hint: if $(k, g) \in S$, then consider $|k^{-1}(\{i\})|$ for $i = 0, 1$.